# typescript use in react-native const undefined

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have a typescript:

```
export const create= () => {
   export const  Size = 5;

   export const now = () => {
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(this.Size); 
   }
}
```

The code runs fine in node.js application, but when I try to use it in react-native, I get:

> Cannot read property 'Size' of undefined

Obviously when converted to javascript to be used in react-native:

```
exports.Size = 5;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need to mark `Size` and `now` with `export`.
2. Arrow functions don't have a `this`. They are using the `this` from the function or class above them. Basically, just use `Size` instead of `this.Size`.

Unrelated, but you may want to look at [AirBnb styleguide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript) for how to write good code.